# Python Event Loops

Tags: python

I have 150 different times and each time 3 things can happen, lets call them 0, 1, and 2. I want to loop through each possibility and check something, what is an easy way to do this. For example, if there were 3 different times instead of 150, I would do this:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
```

and check it like this. However, I don't want to write 150 consecutive loops. What is the easiest way to do this. (efficiency is not a problem for me).

Comment: `import itertools; itertools.product((0, 1, 2), repeat=150)`

Comment: I am trying to find the sum of each loop, how would I do this?

Comment: `for el in itertools.product((0, 1, 2), repeat=150):print(sum(el))`

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot - Edit: how long will this take roughly?

Comment: can you combine the three things into a list of tuples then iterate the list of tuples.  it will be more efficient in this form